# global initialization order with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Let's consider this hunk of code that simply tries to initialize a map from a constexpr array:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

constexpr std::array<std::pair<int, const char *>, 10> my_array {
    { { 0, "dd" },
    { 1, "dd" },
    { 2, "dd" },
    { 7, "dd" },
    { 8, "dd" },
    { 9, "dd" }}
   };

std::map<int, std::string> my_map(std::begin(my_array), std::end(my_array));

int main() {
    return my_map[0].size(); //dummy random operation
}
```

I know there is not way to predict initialization order for the two variables (my_array and my_map). That said, my_array is constexpr, thus should be available a compile time, thus there should be no "initialization order" problem at startup.

Is this code correct or does the initialization order problem remains?

Comment: Are we talking about a single translation unit?

Comment: If you can confirm it is not a problem in a single translation unit, let's assume the array could be in another translation unit to have a complete answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[basic.start.static/2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#2):

> Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is constant-initialized. [...] Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. **All static initialization strongly happens before ([intro.races]) any dynamic initialization**.

So, "Is this code correct?": Yes, as `my_array` is constant initialized, and this happens before dynamic initialization (`my_map`).

(This quote is from the current draft standard, but this rule exists for C++14 as well)